# How to interpret the output of caret::findCorrelation function?

Tags: r, machine-learning, correlation, caret, data-preprocessing

The output I received after applying `findCorrelation` function from the caret package is:

```
> print(highlyCorrelated)
[1]  1 12 13  5 10 19 25 24 15
```

So could I remove all of these features in supervised machine learning? How to interpret the result? Is it that column 1 and 12 are correlated, 13 and 5 are correlated? or some other way?

Comment: The help is at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-90/topics/findCorrelation.  However, IMHO this is an *awful* way to select variables in any machine learning or statistical problem, because it does not account in any reasonable fashion for the complex interrelationships among any subset of three or more variables--and that is known to be potentially important.

Answer (score 2):

From findcorrelation help:

"This function searches through a correlation matrix and returns a vector of integers corresponding to columns to remove to reduce pair-wise correlations."

Comment: It's always good to consult the help.  But this passage isn't very informative, is it?  In particular, it isn't even evident how removing columns could possibly reduce *any* pairwise correlations, unless there is an issue of some incomplete observations.  With a set of complete observations (no missing values), removing columns will not change *any* correlations.